# Imported image not showing in React

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I've got a component on which I need to show an image:

```
import React from 'react'
import background from '../media/content-background.jpg'

function ContentPage(){
    return(
        <div id="content-page">
            <div id="content-header">
                <img href={background} alt='back'/>
            </div>
            <div id="content-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContentPage
```

The image is generated correctly as when I go to the url as specified in the inspector, it shows up in the browser.

[image]

But on the webpage only the alt is shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `src=""` instead of `href=""`.

href is used for specifying where you want a link to go, such as in an  tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the wrong attribute in your `img` tag, use `src` instead:

```
<img src={background} alt='back'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change href to src. href is used for anchor tags and src is used for img tags